# Unix command in python with &

Tags: python, bash

Want to execute below command in python and get output in variable.
I tried to used `Popen`,system methods but it is not grepping particular content like 0 or 1.Python is also throwing some error for & character.
can anyone suggest, how can i prepare command. Using python 2.4.

```
"symtest host port USDSYM | & egrep -e '^0:' -e '^1:' "
```

Comment: Where's your Python code? What is "some error"?

Comment: You will get a bash error: `syntax error near unexpected token '&'`.  The `&` should be at the right-hand end, but it is doubtful that it should be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Popen from subprocess, you can pass you own pipe and then read the pipe.

Comment: I tried it but python threw some error for & character.
basically , i want to grep pattern from output of this cmd.
same unix cmd working on unix prompt.